# qgis script in external IDE fails

Tags: qgis, python

I'm new to Qgis. I have a script that runs successfully inside the Qgis editor, but it fails outside. It returns the alghelp, but fails on running the actual tool so it seems I have the external IDE communicating with modules properly. Ideas?

```
import sys
import os

from qgis.core import *

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin', True)
app = QgsApplication([], True)


import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

alg = 'saga:fillsinksxxlwangliu'
processing.alghelp(alg)
srcDir = r'G:\stest'

for e in os.listdir(srcDir):
    if e.endswith('.tif'):
        print 'Processing ' + e
        processing.runalg(alg, srcDir + os.sep + e, 0.025, srcDir + os.sep + e[:-4] + 'filled.tif')

app.exit()
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

the traceback is

```
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs'
```

Comment: Sorry, It is just not very likely that you will get a response with I had this problem. but it works when I.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have direct experience with this but I found these situations that may help bring you to a solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/python-attribute-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557074/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-get